# Prevent parent category radio button from being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, categories

I've got this function/script that converts the checkboxes into radio buttons (in the Categories metabox), but I need to extend the functionality a little but I'm unsure how to go about it.

The script:

```
function convert_root_cats_to_radio() {
    global $post_type;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#categorychecklist>li>input").each(function(){
    this.disabled = "disabled";
});
jQuery("#categorychecklist>li>ul>li>input").each(function(){
    this.disabled = "disabled";
});
jQuery("#categorychecklist>li>label input").each(function(){
    this.type = 'radio';
});
jQuery("#categorychecklist>li>ul>li>label input").each(function(){
    this.type = 'radio';
});
// Hide the 'most used' tab
jQuery("#category-tabs li:odd").hide();
</script> <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'convert_root_cats_to_radio' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'convert_root_cats_to_radio' );
```

What is needed now: to prevent users from selecting a parent category.

In the image shown below for example, you should be able to select anything except Bandicoot, because Bandicoot is a parent (it has children). Oh and the children items for Bandicoot are allowed to be selected.

So the rule should be: if you're a parent you can't be selected, but your children can.

[image: Category radio buttons]

Comment: are you able to share the rendered html for just this part ? would be helpful to see the traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your output html looks you can make it in one of below options:

```
jQuery("#categorychecklist > li > ul").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent('li').children('label').children('input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

or:

```
jQuery("#categorychecklist > li > ul").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).prev('label').children('input').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

or even better, remove radio:

```
jQuery("#categorychecklist > li > ul").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).prev('label').children('input').remove();
});
```

Comment: Bravo - that works perfectly. I opted to keep the radio visible so the user can see the (limited) hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the comment in the script code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    //assumes that radio button > wrapped around a label > wrapped around li 
    var liObj = $(this).parent().parent();
    if (liObj != undefined && $(liObj).is('li') && $(liObj).has('ul').length > 0) {
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='test'>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='cat' />1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='cat' />2</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='cat' />3</label>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <label>
          <input type='radio' name='cat' />3-1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type='radio' name='cat' />3-2</label>

        <ul id='test'>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type='radio' name='cat' />3-2-1</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type='radio' name='cat' />3-2-2</label>
          </li>
        </ul>



      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>


</ul>
```